# Dockerizing a MERN stack app, how to define ports

Tags: reactjs, docker, mern

I want to dockerize my MERN app, here is the dockerfile for my frontend:

```
FROM node:18.8-alpine
COPY . ./app
WORKDIR /app
RUN npm install
EXPOSE 3000
CMD ["npm", "start"]
```

and here is the dockerfile for my backend:

```
FROM node:18.8-alpine
COPY . ./app
WORKDIR /app
RUN npm install
EXPOSE 3000
CMD ["node", "server.js"]
```

I also want to use docker-compose to run both frontend and backend together and this is the config file:

```
version: '3.8'
services:
  backend:
    build: ./backend
    container_name: backend_C
    ports:
      - 80:80
  frontend:
    build: ./frontend
    container_name: frontend_C
    ports:
      - 3000:3000

    stdin_open: true
    tty: true
```

The problem is since both my backend and frontend run on port 3000, there would be a conflict when I run my images. I don't know how to specify and change the ports for them.

Comment: maybe a stupid question but why do you have both running on port 3000

Comment: I'd host the frontend in Nginx and have it pass requests on `/api` through to the backend. That way you only need to expose one port and you get rid of any CORS issues etc.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can simply specify different host ports mapping to the same container ports:

```
version: '3.8'
services:
  backend:
    build: ./backend
    container_name: backend_C
    ports:
      - 3000:3000
  frontend:
    build: ./frontend
    container_name: frontend_C
    ports:
      - 8080:3000

    stdin_open: true
    tty: true
```

Now your backend is available on port `3000` and your frontend on port `8080`